# Remote push notification management

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have a question about iOS Push Notification.

How can I know the notification data info that I received when the app is not Active?

When the app is active I use this code to manage the notification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
//manage the notification...
       }
}
```

But, when the app is not active and I receive a remote push notification, I would to show the correct view when the user open the app by notification tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `launchOptions` `NSDictionary` in your App Delegate method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

If your app was opened via a push notification there will be an object for the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`. You can then handle that object:

```
NSDictionary *remoteNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

if (remoteNotif) {
    //Handle remote notification
    [self handleReceivedPush:remoteNotification];
}
```

`handleReceivedPush:` is a method you would need to write yourself, here you can decide what to do.